# opencv vs 2010 dependencies issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, include

I am having an issue with trying to setup opencv 2.4.6 with visual studio ultimate 2010 on a 64-bit windows 8 machine. I know to add in the includes and dll references, but when I execute the code I have it shows this huge external linking error:

code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
   Mat img = imread("mypic.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); //read the image data in the            file "MyPic.JPG" and store it in 'img'

  if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
  {
      cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
      //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
      return -1;
  }

  namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
  imshow("MyWindow", img); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

  waitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress

  destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

  return 0;
}
```

and the error is:

```
1>Build started 7/28/2013 3:08:34 AM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\opencv_2.0.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl       cv::destroyWindow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?destroyWindow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0_InputArray@cv@@QAE@ABVMat@1@@Z)   referenced in function _main
1>core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::namedWindow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class     std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?namedWindow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function _main
1>core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function _main
1>core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall   cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public:   void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YAHPAHH@Z) referenced   in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\Parker\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\opencv_2.0\Debug\opencv_2.0.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.67
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I did try adding the .lib files in the additional dependencies, but vs2010 said it does not detect them, since I did see another post with a problem just like mine. The include directory includes the generic "include" folder along with the opencv and opencv2 folders. I then added the build\x64\vc10\lib, bin and staticlib to the additional lib dirs. The opencv was also extracted to just the c:\ drive so there should not be any problem there. I thank everyone in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace:

```
opencv_highgui243.lib
```

on:

```
opencv_highgui243d.lib
```

Comment: OP is using OpenCV 2.4.6.

Comment: ok I tried moving all of the debug .lib's in a separate folder and then setting the additional dependencies to the debug folder. I still get the same error.I will still try to poke around in vs to see if I am missing anything. Also should I be aware of anything in the additional dependencies in "linker" >> "input" area? again thanks

Comment: ohh never mind I figured out something with the directories of the libraries were wrong too, but you did help me a lot of the debug vs. release libraries. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have included release libraries instead of debug versions.

Because you have built in `debug` mode, libraries should also be of `debug` version like:

```
opencv_highgui243d.lib
```

instead of

```
opencv_highgui243.lib
```